# When trying to connect data between pages using JavaScript and using innerText to bind the data, the event is not occurring

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement a complaint website using JavaScript as a side project. However, I'm having trouble connecting the data between the index page and the add page.

In the 'add.html' page, I'm retrieving the values of the title input and description input in the 'databinding' function, and in the 'create_table' function, I'm setting 'innerText = value1'. But when I click the confirmation button, no event seems to be triggered. I'm curious about what could be causing this.

Also, after clicking the confirmation button, I would like to navigate to the list page after the event occurs. I'm wondering how to achieve this.
[index.html]

```
        <div class="board_table">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>No</th>
                        <th>title</th>
                        <th>user</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="table_list">
                    <tr>
                        <td><p>1</p></td>
                        <td><p>title</p></td>
                        <td><p>1</p></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="board_post">
            <a href="add.html" class="add">add</a>
          
        </div>
```

[add.html]

```
 <div class="board_component">
        
            <div class="board_post">
               
                <div class="board_body">
                    <strong>title</strong>
                    <input type="text" class="data_title">
                    <p>explain</p>
                    <input type="text" class="data_exp">
                    <button class="add_btn">confirm</button>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

[script.js]

```
const table_list = document.querySelector(".table_list");
const add_btn = document.querySelector(".add_btn");
const data_title = document.querySelector(".data_title");
const data_exp = document.querySelector(".data_exp");

let counter = 1;

function create_table(value1,value2){
    const tr = document.createElement("tr");
    const td = document.createElement("td");
    const num = document.createElement("span");
    const title = dicument.createElement("span");

    counter++;
    num.innerHTML = counter;
    title.innerText = value1;
    td.appendChild(num,title);
    tr.appendChild(td);
    table_list.appendChild(tr);
}

function databinding(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const currentValue = data_title.value;
    const currentValue2 = data_exp.value;
    create_table(currentValue,currentValue2);
}

function init(){
    add_btn.addEventListener("click",create_table)
}

init()
```